# Views: Exposed filter If anonymous. Filter by user field if authenticated

Tags: entities, views, users

I have created two 'Postal code' (text) fields: one in a content type (Event) and another in the user account. I have also created a view showing Events. Now I would like to do the following:

When a user go to the events view:
  If the user is anonnymous a exposed filter must be show.
  If the user is authenticated, show only events with the postal code of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the module [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters)?

For example, you could create a filter which checks if the user is logged in (or has a postal code) and set a dependency to that filter in your postal code filter.

You could also write some custom code (which might be easier in my opinion):

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Get the current logged in user object.
  global $user;

  // Check for the exposed form, you would do good to add
  // some extra checks to make sure you only identify your
  // postal code exposed filter.
  if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    // Load the full user object.
    $account = user_load($user->uid);

    // Check if the user has a postal code.
    if (!empty($account->field_postal_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
      // Hide the exposed postal code field.
      $form['field_postal_code']['#type'] = 'hidden';
      // Set a default value for the exposed postal code field.
      $form['field_postal_code']['#default_value'] = $account->field_postal_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to apply the filter immediately without needing to submit the form. You could use `hook_views_pre_view` for that:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  global $user;

  if ($view->name == 'your_view') {
    // Do the same user postal code check as above here.

    // Apply the exposed filter.
    $view->exposed_input['field_postal_code'] = $account->field_postal_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the hook_views_pre_views part works, though, so you might need to do a little research there.

Comment: I have installed the module but I havent get it. Could you please explain a little more ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Just create two views. Have one accessable to anonymous users and the other for logged in users and set the filters appropriately.